Entropy of a random vector with random discrete elements and random length
We have a discrete random vector $x = [x_1, \dots, x_m]$ where $m$ is a random variable with values in $\{1, \dots, M\}$. Each element $x_i$ is a discrete random variable in $\{1, \dots, N\}$. For example, you can think of the generation process to first sample a length $m \sim p_m(\cdot)$ and then sample the elements $x_1, \dots, x_m$ according to a joint distribution.
Let $p$ denote the probability distribution over $x$. I am interested in computing the maximum of the following quantity:
$$- \sum_x \frac{1}{m} p(x) \log p(x)$$
This is similar to Shannon entropy but also normalized with the length of the random vector $x$. Of course, given $x$, its length $m$ is known and no longer a random variable.
My attempt: We can write the above term by conditioning on the length:
\begin{align}
& - \sum_m \frac{1}{m} p_m(m) \sum_{x|m} p(x|m) \Big[ \log (p(m)) + \log (p(x|m)) \Big]\\
= & \sum_m \frac{1}{m} p_m(m)  \times - \sum_{x|m} p(x|m) \log (p(x|m)) + \sum_m \frac{1}{m} p_m(m)  \log (p(m)) \sum_{x|m} p(x|m)
\end{align}
The sum $ - \sum_x p(x|m) \log p(x|m)$ itself is an entropy, so its maximum is at uniform distribution over $x$ with dimension $m$, which is $\log N^m = m \log N$. So the maximum of the first term is $ \sum_m p_m(m) \frac{1}{m} \times m \log N = \log N.$
$\sum_m \frac{1}{m} p_m(m)  \times - \sum_{x|m} p(x|m) \log (p(x|m))  \leq \log N$
For the second term, we have $\sum_{x|m} p(x|m) = 1$ so
$\sum_m \frac{1}{m} p_m(m)  \log (p^{-1}(m)) \sum_{x|m} p(x|m) = \sum_m \frac{1}{m} p_m(m) \log (p^{-1}(m)) \leq \sum_m p_m(m) \log (p^{-1}(m)) = \log M$.
The inequalities use the fact that $m \geq 1$ and that $\sum_m p_m(m) \log (p^{-1}(m))$ is Shannon entropy with maximum of $\log M$.
Is my approach correct?
